# Android ViewPager Remove Separator

Tags: android, android-viewpager, separator

I have a ViewPager that showing a list of images.

I set the width so it'll show around 3 pages in one screen.
But the problem is, there is a separator that mysteriously come between pages.

[image]

I want to remove them, do you have any suggestions how to remove them?

Here is my code for ViewPager

```
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/subcategory_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/category_subcategory_pager_height"
        android:layout_below="@+id/category_thumbnail"
        android:background="#abcdef"
        />
```

Code to set with of adapter

```
    @Override
    public float getPageWidth(final int position) {
        if(getCount()>3){
            // this will have 4 pages in a single view
            return 0.29f;
        } else {
            return 1f/getCount();
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's not a separator. That's the `ViewPager`'s background. Notice how it's not there between the first two images, and it's the same color you've set for the `background` on the `<ViewPager>` element.

Comment: That's it, I give the background so can find the reason why there is a line like separator on there.
And I change the page width into 0.3f and the line is gone now
Thanks for the reply

Comment: This looks like **margin** added in Adapter view.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the background of viewpager from xml.

Comment: It stil have line but the color is white. I give Background just for know why the line is appear
I edit the page width into 0.3f and the line is gone
Thanks for answering anyway